# Comprobar que BigDecimal es un valor númerico java

Tags: java

Como validar que un BigDecimal cumple con valores numéricos con anotaciones javax.validation.constraints ya que con el regex no me sirve

```
@Pattern(regexp = "[0-9]*")
@Digits(integer = 6, fraction = 2, message = "Inválido")
    private BigDecimal banda;

public BigDecimal getBanda() {
        return this.banda;
    }

    public void setBanda(BigDecimal banda) {
        this.banda = banda;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Para validar un BigDecimal, puedes usar **@Digits**, **@DecimalMin** (si deseamos establecer un número mínimo) y su contraparte **@DecimalMax** (un máximo).

Como no especificas qué comprobación te gustaría realizar, te dejo como ejemplo si quisieras validar que el BigDecimal sea mayor o igual a cero.

```
@Digits(integer=6, fraction=2)
@DecimalMin(value = "0.0", inclusive = true)
```

Comment: deseo validar que lo que ingresa sean valores numéricos y no letras

Comment: En teoría debería ser suficiente con @Digits. Allí se especifica que el dato se compone por un entero con decimales. Podrías complementarlo con el método booleano StringUtils.isNumeric() si estás recibiendo un String y deseas validar que sea numérico, pero al caso sería redundante.